# How to read a complete input split as a single record in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

By default, hadoop uses line record reader which reads the input split line by line.
I have a requirement to read a complete input split in one read, ie as a single record. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to write your own customised record reader
so that it'll read the whole file as a single record

you can see this in "hadoop definitive guide 4th edition" PAGE - 228

this example may help you

```
public class WholeFileInputFormat
extends FileInputFormat<NullWritable, BytesWritable> {
@Override
protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path file) {
return false;
}
@Override
public RecordReader<NullWritable, BytesWritable> createRecordReader(
InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException,
InterruptedException {
WholeFileRecordReader reader = new WholeFileRecordReader();
reader.initialize(split, context);
return reader;
}
}



class WholeFileRecordReader extends RecordReader<NullWritable, BytesWritable> {
private FileSplit fileSplit;
private Configuration conf;
private BytesWritable value = new BytesWritable();
private boolean processed = false;
@Override
public void initialize(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context)
throws IOException, InterruptedException {
this.fileSplit = (FileSplit) split;
this.conf = context.getConfiguration();
}
@Override
public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
if (!processed) {
byte[] contents = new byte[(int) fileSplit.getLength()];
Path file = fileSplit.getPath();
FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
FSDataInputStream in = null;
try {
in = fs.open(file);
IOUtils.readFully(in, contents, 0, contents.length);
value.set(contents, 0, contents.length);
} finally {
IOUtils.closeStream(in);
}
processed = true;
return true;
}
return false;
}
@Override
public NullWritable getCurrentKey() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
return NullWritable.get();
}
@Override
public BytesWritable getCurrentValue() throws IOException,
InterruptedException {
return value;
}
@Override
Input Formats | 229
public float getProgress() throws IOException {
return processed ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
}
@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
// do nothing
}
}


public class SmallFilesToSequenceFileConverter extends Configured
implements Tool {
static class SequenceFileMapper
extends Mapper<NullWritable, BytesWritable, Text, BytesWritable> {
private Text filenameKey;
@Override
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
InterruptedException {
InputSplit split = context.getInputSplit();
Path path = ((FileSplit) split).getPath();
filenameKey = new Text(path.toString());
}
@Override
protected void map(NullWritable key, BytesWritable value, Context context)
throws IOException, InterruptedException {
context.write(filenameKey, value);
}
}
@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
Job job = JobBuilder.parseInputAndOutput(this, getConf(), args);
if (job == null) {
return -1;
}
job.setInputFormatClass(WholeFileInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(BytesWritable.class);
job.setMapperClass(SequenceFileMapper.class);
return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new SmallFilesToSequenceFileConverter(), args);
System.exit(exitCode);
}
}
```